# SSRS Hide one legend from each series

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've been looking around at SO and Google but not really found anything that matches my current problem.

I'm making a stacked barchart based on two series. One series shows late, outstanding issues and one shows only outstanding (still within the due date).

The problem is that my legend shows four individual items, whereas I only want two (one for each series).

I've attempted by adding this in the **Series Properties>Legend>Do not show this series in a legend formula (*fx*)**:

```
=IIF(Fields!ReadyForWork.Value = 1, False, True)
```

This basically checks to only display the legend if the value is 0. However this hides both the items in the legend, not just the one.

The relevant data I'm working with right now is:

- **TRK_Feature_LKID** (basically each row's PK)
- **DateToBeActioned** (important for maroon) - Used to determine if **Date.Now()** is higher to a set date when the issue should have been resolved.
- **ReadyForWork** - A numeric value (0 / 1) to see if the item is ready for work.
- **AcountablePerson** - The name of the responsible person (x-axis).

In below image I want to remove the red 'Late Issue' and the maroon 'True - ReadyForWork'.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix this by adding a separate field in the report's dataset that basically checked whether the DateToBeActioned was outside of GETDATE:

```
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [DateToBeActioned], GETDATE()) >= 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END as 'Outstanding'
```

And by using that field in the legend as well as specifying that the dataset should only retrieve issues that had not been completed:

```
WHERE ReadyForWork = 0
```

I was able to set the legend to only show the two preferred items.

So for anyone who might face a similar issue; one way of fixing it might be to have a seperate field in your dataset that checks the case that checks for the parameters you don't want / you want to show in the legend.